Adaptive screen layout in Unity

How can I go about creating this layout for a (2D) screen in Unity?
Requirements:

 middle area is 50% height of the screen

top and bottom areas are 25% of the screen each

When I add a game object to the middle container, I want to scale it such that it will scale to either 80% of the container height (if it’s a tall object), or 75% of the container width (if it’s a wide object).

Add four game objects to the bottom container, equally spaced. Each object should scale to 85% height of the bottom container.


Can you add objects to containers like this in Unity? I know everything is a game object with a transform (position), but it’s not clear to me how to have them take up areas of the screen, or which APIs to use when adding objects to have them respect parent containers. I tried things like horizontal and vertical layout groups but those didn’t seem to have any effect.

is this for 2D UI? In that case you could just go with the new UIToolkit which basically is quite similar to HTML + CSS (they call it UXML + USS) ... if this is for 3D ... You could either use separate cameras to compose your screen using different Viewports ... or you have to go fancy and code that ^^

Yes, it's for 2D. Did not expect HTML/UXML to be the answer here, that sounds awful TBH. I mean, this is a game, not a menu. Isn't it common to position things in a game scene in a way that adapts to different screen sizes?

Well you can of course also replicate this scaling yourself if it is for actual world space game objects .. you probably have to ^^ .. that's why I was asking whether this is for UI .. because then UI toolkit would be your go to as it handles exactly that already

You can access the Screen.height and Screen.width. And then calculate the correct positioning and scaling manually.
To find the center point of the screen in world space you can use
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera.ScreenToWorldPoint.html
